# WebSockets + PHP Sockets not working

Tags: javascript, php, sockets, websocket

Let's start from the beginning: I have installed **Wamp Server (version: 2.4.9, php: 5.5.12)**, and I want to create a simple chat with web sockets.

Great, for this i create two files:

**Connect.js**

```
window.onload = function() { 

var form = document.getElementById('mensagem-formulario'); 
var mensagemTexto = document.getElementById('mensagem');
var listaMensagem = document.getElementById('mensagens');
var socketStatus = document.getElementById('status'); 
var btnFechar = document.getElementById('close'); 

var socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');

socket.onopen = function(event) { 

socketStatus.innerHTML = 'Connect with ' + event.currentTarget.URL; socketStatus.className = 'open'; 

};

socket.onerror = function(error) { 

console.log('Error: ' + error); 

socketStatus.innerHTML = 'Error: ' + error;

};

form.onsubmit = function(e) { e.preventDefault(); /
var mensagem = mensagemTexto.value; 
socket.send(mensagem); 
listaMensagem.innerHTML += '<li class="envia"><span>Enviado:</span>' + mensagem + '</li>'; 
mensagemTexto.value = ''; return false; 

};

socket.onmessage = function(event) { 
var mensagem = event.data; listaMensagem.innerHTML += '<li class="recebida"><span>Recebida:</span>' + mensagem + '</li>'; 
};

socket.onclose = function(event) { 

socketStatus.innerHTML = 'Disconectado do WebSocket.'; socketStatus.className = 'closed'; 

};

btnFechar.onclick = function(e) { 
e.preventDefault(); 
socket.close(); return false; 
};

};
```

**Server.php**

```
<?php

    $server = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
    socket_set_option($server, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1);
    socket_bind($server, "localhost", 8080);
    socket_listen($server);

    $client = socket_accept($server);

    $message = socket_read($client, 5000);

    $matches = array();

    preg_match('#Sec-WebSocket-Key: (.*)\r\n#', $message, $matches);

    $new_key = new_key($matches[1]);

    $new_message = "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\n";
    $new_message .= "Upgrade: websocket\r\n";
    $new_message .= "Connection: Upgrade\r\n";
    $new_message .= "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: " . $new_key . "\r\n\r\n";

    socket_write($client, $new_message, strlen($new_message));

    $new_message = "Test message !";

    socket_write($client, $new_message, strlen($new_message));

    function new_key($key)
    {
        $key .= "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11";
        $key = sha1($key);
        $new_key = '';

        for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($key); $i+=2)
        {
            $new_key .= chr(intval($key[$i] . $key[$i+1], 16));
        }

        $new_key = base64_encode($new_key);

        return $new_key;
    }

    /* End of file server.php */

    ?>
```

Great, now lets test this code:

- First of all I start my Wamp Server
- Now I open the file server.php in browser.
- Great, I think the connection is open (because file doesn't stop to load)
- Now its time to open connect.js and see the results.

When I open connect.js the server.php stop to load in another tab, in console log javascript send to me the following errors:

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080/' failed: One or more
>   reserved bits are on: reserved1 = 1, reserved2 = 0, reserved3 = 1

How can I solve this problem? Is a syntax problem or server problem? (I don't want to use node.js, socket.io and others, I'm trying to do it by hand).

Comment: I don't think that you can use websockets with php, because script can only run in limited number of time, but maybe I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

> Solution

The problem with this code is the php server, So if you're having the same problem, you need to create a new file called **server.php** and put this code below inside him:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
set_time_limit(0);
$adr = "localhost";
echo $adr."\n\n";
$port = 8080;

$m_sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
socket_set_option($m_sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1);
$cls = array($m_sock);

socket_bind($m_sock, $adr, $port);
socket_listen($m_sock, 5);
echo "Starting server...\n\n";

do{
    usleep(500);
    $changed = $cls;
    $val = @socket_select($changed,$write=NULL,$except=NULL,0);
    foreach ($changed as $sock) {
        if($sock === $m_sock){
            echo "wait...\n\n";
            $msgsock = socket_accept($m_sock);
            array_push($cls, $msgsock);
            echo "Connected...\n\n";
            socket_recv($msgsock, $hds, 4096, 0);

            if(preg_match("/Sec-WebSocket-Key: (.*)\r\n/",$hds,$matchs)){
                echo "do handshake...\n\n";

                $key = $matchs[1] . '258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11';
                $key =  base64_encode(sha1($key, true)); 
                $headers = "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\n".
                "Upgrade: websocket\r\n".
                "Connection: Upgrade\r\n".
                "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: $key".
                "\r\n\r\n";
                socket_write($msgsock, $headers);
                echo "handshak done...\n";
            }
        }else{
            $bytes = socket_recv($sock, $data, 2048, null);
            $d = unmask($data);
            foreach ($cls as $socket) {
                if($socket != $m_sock && $val > 0){
                    try{
                       socket_write($socket,(encode($d))); 
                    }catch(Exception $e){
                        unset($cls[$socket]);
                        socket_close($cls[$socket]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } 


}while(1);
socket_close($m_sock);


function unmask($payload) {
    $length = ord($payload[1]) & 127;

    if($length == 126) {
        $masks = substr($payload, 4, 4);
        $data = substr($payload, 8);
    }
    elseif($length == 127) {
        $masks = substr($payload, 10, 4);
        $data = substr($payload, 14);
    }
    else {
        $masks = substr($payload, 2, 4);
        $data = substr($payload, 6);
    }

    $text = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($data); ++$i) {
        $text .= $data[$i] ^ $masks[$i%4];
    }
    return $text;
}

function encode($text)
{
    // 0x1 text frame (FIN + opcode)
    $b1 = 0x80 | (0x1 & 0x0f);
    $length = strlen($text);

    if($length <= 125)
        $header = pack('CC', $b1, $length);
    elseif($length > 125 && $length < 65536)
        $header = pack('CCS', $b1, 126, $length);
    elseif($length >= 65536)
        $header = pack('CCN', $b1, 127, $length);

    return $header.$text;
}


?>
```